# Eigenspace and Isomorphisms of a n-dimensional vector space $V$ over $F$ with minimal polynomial of degree 2

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and let $A: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation whose minimal polynomial $m_A$ is of degree 2. Consider $V$ as a module over $F[X]$ where $x$ acts by $A$.

a) List the possible isomorphism types of $V$, for each possible factorization of $m_A$ into irreducible.

b) Show that if $m_A$ has a root, then there is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that the eigenspace has dimension $\geq \frac{n}{2}$.

For a) We know that $V$ is isomorphic to $\frac{F[X]}{p(x)}$, where $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$. If $m_A$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then let $p(x)=m_A$. Otherwise
we can to factor $m_A$ into an irreducible linear functions over $F$ as $m_A$ has degree 2. Let $p_1$ and $p_1$ be such linear functions. Then use $p_1, p_2$ as $p(x)$. Hence, we have 3 possible isomorphic types.

For b), I want to use the fact that $V= K_{\lambda_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus K_{\lambda_k}$, where $K_\lambda$ is the generalized eigenspace. Suppose $m_A$ has a root. Then $m_A$ can have at most 2 distinct roots.

Case 1: Suppose $m_A$ has 2 distinct roots, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$. Then we have $K_{\lambda_i}= E_{\lambda_i}$, where $E_{\lambda_i}$ is the eigenspace for $\lambda_1$. Since $V= K_{\lambda_1} \oplus K_{\lambda_2}$, we are done.

Case 2: Suppose $m_A$ has 1 root $\lambda$ of multiplicity 2. Then $V=K_\lambda= N(A-\lambda I)^2$. From here, I'm not sure how to conclude with a good explanation.

Could someone please check if my thinking is correct? And any help will be appreciated!

Comment: "We know that $V$ is isomorphic to $\frac{F[X]}{p(x)}$ [...]"
I do not think this is true.

Comment: Do you know of the theorem that any finitely generated module $M$ over a PID $R$ is isomorphic to $R^n \oplus (R / \langle x_1 \rangle) \oplus \cdots (R / \langle x_m \rangle)$ for some $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ (where $0 \in \mathbb{N}$) and $x_1, \ldots, x_m \in R$?  Then in your case, $F[X]$ is a PID, and $V$ being finite dimensional over $F$ will imply $n = 0$ in that decomposition; and $A$ being annihilated by $m_A$ will imply each $x_i$ divides $m_A$.